# How to write standalone spark app after I modify the Spark source code

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I have downloaded the `Spark 1.3.1` source code and import it into `IDEA`. And then I modify its source code to extend its functionality.

In such case, how could I write standalone spark app ? I changed the `spark-sql` module, and if my app wants to use my new extension, I think the following dependency :

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "1.3.0"
```

cannot fit my demand, since it still uses the original dependency)

p.s.  I have run `mvn build` to build the modified code.

So, How can I write a standalone spark app using the modified code ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install your customised Spark Jar into the local mvn repository

```sh
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx2g -XX:MaxPermSize=512M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m"
mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.2 -Dhadoop.version=2.2.0 -DskipTests clean package install
```

2. Change the jar's version to point to the local version

```sh
resolvers += Resolver.mavenLocal

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % source-code-version
```

the `source-code-version` is what you have in spark's pom.xml `<version>`